# Поиск совпадений в двух массивах

Tags: perl

Есть два массива,

```
@array1("20.08.2018 21.08.2018 22.08.2018")
@array2("18.08.2018 19.08.2018 20.08.2018")
```

Как найти все вхождения из @array2 в @array1? Даты всегда идут строго по порядку возрастания, без пропусков дней. Т.е. из данного примера мне нужно 
получить следующее:

```
18.08.2018 19.08.2018 - свободные дни.
20.09.2018 - занятые.
```

Спасибо!

Comment: если перл достаточно свеж то можно так `my @array3 = grep { $_ ~~ @array1 } @array2`

Comment: norbornen нет, к сожалению. ~~ не работает! ((

Comment: какая версия perl?

Answer (score 0):

Простой вариант с использованием хэша:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = split(/\s+/, "20.08.2018 21.08.2018 22.08.2018");
my @array2 = split(/\s+/, "18.08.2018 19.08.2018 20.08.2018");

my %hash1 = map {$_=>1} @array1;
my @arrayExists = grep { $hash1{$_} } @array2;
my @arrayNotExists = grep { !$hash1{$_} } @array2;

print 'EXISTS: '.join(', ', @arrayExists)."\n";
print 'NOT EXISTS: '.join(', ', @arrayNotExists)."\n";
```

Вариант с использованием [cмартматчинга](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;

my @array1 = split(/\s+/, "20.08.2018 21.08.2018 22.08.2018");
my @array2 = split(/\s+/, "18.08.2018 19.08.2018 20.08.2018");

my @arrayExists = grep {$_ ~~ @array1} @array2;
my @arrayNotExists = grep {!($_ ~~ @array1)} @array2;

print 'EXISTS: '.join(', ', @arrayExists)."\n";
print 'NOT EXISTS: '.join(', ', @arrayNotExists)."\n";
```

Вывод в консоль:

> EXISTS: 20.08.2018
>
> NOT EXISTS: 18.08.2018, 19.08.2018

*Понятно, что в обоих случаях можно заполнить массивы и в одном проходе по `@array2` :)*

---

В Online Perl Interpreter проверяем работоспособность [первого](https://ideone.com/vCmQLr) и [второго](https://ideone.com/gdxeKY) скрипта.

Comment: Ничего не получается. Везде $VAR1 = [ ];

Comment: @AIex к сожалению, по четвергам я не могу пользоваться своими телепатическими способностями - в любой день недели могу, а вот по четвергам - нет, так что тебе прийдётся самому написать что именно не получается и что тебе не понятно. чтобы тебе было легче бороться с этой задачей я снабдил решение ссылками на эти скрипты в "Online Perl Interpreter".

Answer (score 0):

В общем сделал так.

```
foreach $line(@array2) {
if ( grep( /^$line$/, @array1 ) ) {
   День занят!
}
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: серьёзно? а можешь в https://ideone.com/ показать полное решение?